# How large are blocks of data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, disk-space

I'm working in SQL Server 2008 R2 and have created a query that gathers and sums the total of data files and log files' sizes. However, I can't find how much actual disk space a single block of SQL data takes up on the disk so I can convert it into something more meaningful.

Here is the script:

```
DECLARE @DataSize INT
DECLARE @LogSize INT
SELECT @DataSize = SUM(size) from sys.database_files where type_desc = 'Rows'
SELECT @LogSize = SUM(size) from sys.database_files where type_desc = 'Log'
PRINT @DataSize
PRINT @LogSize
```

How large is one block of space? Would it be easy to convert those two integer variables into something more meaningful for a sysadmin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the column documentation of [`sys.database_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> size:  Current size of the file, in 8-KB pages.

So a more meaningful query might be something like this:

```
SELECT
    df.name AS LogicalFileName,
    df.physical_name AS PhysicalPath,
    CONVERT(int, (((df.size * 8192) / 1024.0) / 1024.0)) AS SizeInMB
    FROM sys.database_files df;
```

(You can expand on that further as necessary.)

Comment: It's worth adding that SQL Server does data file I/O in chunks of 8 pages, or 64 KB "extents", so optimize storage around that rather than individual 8 KB pages.

Comment: Additionally, if the disk is dedicated to SQL Server data files then format it using an 8192 byte allocation unit.

Comment: Actually no - a 8192yte allocation unit would be utterly stupid. As SQL Server does all IO in extends - you need to format it witha 64k allocation unit. Then NTFS allocation units and IO operations line up. SQL Server never does smaller IO than 64k.

Comment: @TomTom Actually no, SQL Server does not do all IO in extents. The tests demonstrated in [Dissecting SQL Server physical reads with Extended Events and Process monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2013/03/14/dissecting-sql-server-physical-reads-with-extended-events-and-process-monitor.aspx) and [Detailed Windows I/O: Process Monitor](http://sqlvelocity.typepad.com/blog/2011/04/detailed-windows-io-process-monitor.html) are easily replicated (and interesting to observe).

Comment: That said, 64k allocation is still the recommendation although this [typically has no effect on performance](http://www.kendalvandyke.com/2009/02/disk-performance-hands-on-part-2-raid.html) (IOPS, MB/sec or latency).